# Writting multi-strip JPEG encoded TIFF image failed with some image width

Tags: java, image, compression, jpeg, tiff

I am working on a TIFF encoder to encode with new JPEG compression (Technote2). To make it more like a new style JPEG, I am writing 2 strips with JPEG tables written separately. It works fine most of the time but with some special cases - image width equals 1000, 2000, 3000 etc, the encoded image become all gray color. I am sure the problem is not from any kind of overflow of data type and there isn't any error shown. I inspected the tags with AsTiffTagViewer but couldn't see any problem there.

Note: if I write only 1 strip, there is no problem for any image size.

The following is the relevant part:

```
    int rowsPerStrip = imageHeight/2 + 1; // Two strips
    JPEGWriter jpgWriter = new JPEGWriter(); 
    // Write first strip
    jpgWriter.write(Arrays.copyOfRange(pixels, 0, imageWidth*(imageHeight/2 + 1)), imageWidth, imageHeight/2 + 1, randomOS); 
    // Another strip
    jpgWriter.write(Arrays.copyOfRange(pixels, imageWidth*(imageHeight/2 + 1), pixels.length), imageWidth, imageHeight - imageHeight/2 - 1, randomOS);
```

Here randomOS is a random access output stream to work with TIFF and pixels is an int array for the whole image.

The tags shown by ASTiffTagViewer for One example image I have with dimension 2000x3000 are as follows:

```
> SubFileType (1 Long): Zero
> ImageWidth (1 Long): 2000
> ImageLength (1 Long): 3000
> BitsPerSample (3 Short): 8, 8, 8
> Compression (1 Short): JPEG Technote #2
> Photometric (1 Short): YCbCr
> StripOffsets (2 Long): 8, 82430
> SamplesPerPixel (1 Short): 3
> RowsPerStrip (1 Short): 1501
> StripByteCounts (2 Long): 82422, 82422
> PlanarConfig (1 Short): Contig
> DateTime (24 ASCII): 2014:05:28 13:29:54 EDT
> JpegTables (574 Undefined):
> YCbCrSubsampling (2 Short): 1, 1
> ReferenceBlackWhite (3 Rational):
```

The original image is just a fill with orange color, the same number of StripByteCounts should not be the problem.

I have looking through Technote2 trying to find something I might have missed without success. I am hoping someone here may give me some clue as where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Post a link to a good image and a bad and I'll tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @BitBank: Thanks for you interest in this post. I know you are an image expert. I put the links to the good tiff (2001x3000) and the bad tiff (2000x3000). You might be able to figure out the problem.

Comment: I examined your files and the problem is not in TIFF tags or file structure, but in the raw image data. The bad image is encoded as pure gray (0x80 in Y and Cb and Cr). I can't tell where the problem is occurring, but the image data (before encoding) is where you need to look.

Comment: @BitBank: it sounds reasonable albeit weir as it only happens with some image width. Anyway, thanks for you time and I will go with your suggestions and see what happens.

Comment: If the only difference between good and bad is the width, then it is likely a bug in the JPEG encoder. Using Java means your choices are limited. Can you test another Java JPEG encoder? A workaround is to pad the width to values that produce proper output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54669/discussion-between-dragon66-and-bitbank).

Comment: @BitBank: problem solved! It actually is a bug in my JPEGWriter when expanding image dimension to multiple of 8. Would you post an answer with your suggestions to this question so that I can accept it?

Comment: I can't really take credit for you fixing your own bug. I'm glad you solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make a clean close to this question:

Problem solved! It actually is a bug in my JPEGWriter when expanding image dimension to multiple of 8. Thanks to BitBank for stimulating discussion.